# sed substitution syntax

Tags: nvidia, deepin

I found this guide to installing a legacy Nvidia driver to Linux:

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Version_304.135_.28legacy_GPUs.29-1

And I am having trouble with this particular command.

```
# aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver
```

that command is allegedly to grab the particular driver I need.

I suppose "uname" is my user name, but the sed command seems to be missing some values. I'm using the latest Deepin, and when I try to install the drivers with the standard command, it always grabs the latest driver, which this card cannot use.

Comment: [What does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/498679/edit) your `uname -r` produce? Then, what does `uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//'` produce? (Call the output of that command, `WHATEVER`.) Now, do you have `linux-headers-WHATEVER` in the package repository, where `WHATEVER` matches that output? If not, you're going to need to hunt for a suitable alternative.

Comment: If you had to reset your StackExchange account, why not ask the moderators for assistance. The ones we have here are pretty helpful, and I see no reason why they wouldn't be on [SE] too.

Comment: Finally, for now anyway, `uname` is nothing to do with your username. It's a command that returns various bits of headline information about your system's currently running kernel. You can read its documentation with `man uname`.

Comment: Bottom line: type what it says: `u` `n` `a` `m` `e` `⁠ ⁠` `-` `r` `|` `s` `e` `d` `⁠ ⁠` `'` `s` `/` `[` `^` `-` `]` `*` `-` `[` `^` `-` `]` `*` `-` `/` `/` `'`.  There are no placeholders in that command.

Comment: Thanks I ran it that way, apparently it is throwing some error. I’ll come back here and edit this once I run it again and put that error up.

Comment: Ok it's tossing me this: "No candidate version found for linux-headers-generic" - even though I have added the repo where the file is supposed to exist.

Comment: Ah, I neglected to run an apt-get update, and it appears there are a slew of dependencies that are not automatically added. I'll run it again after I install the dependencies.

Comment: All right, every single dependency required, is already installed. I even downloaded the deb package for the driver, it still says I need a support package (that’s already there). But my deepin-wm is no longer crashing, so I’ll just stick with what I’ve got. Thanks for explaining how that sed command works. The error threw me off, thought there was more to the command.